# VerifyError: Error #1079: Native methods are not allowed in loaded code

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash

I have an Android/iOS app compiled in AS3. I was having issues and was advised to upgrade to Flash Builder 4.7 (from 4.6). I did so, and when I try running with the new Air 3.4 I get the following error:

```
VerifyError: Error #1079: Native methods are not allowed in loaded code.
```

Comment: if you are using any libraries (.swc files), then set the .swc linkage to external

Comment: also I assume that you do not have any code executing in any loaded assets

Comment: All SWCs are already set to external. No assets are loaded externally. This happens right away at runtime anyway before anything even loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried uninstalling Flash Builder 4.7 64 bit and installing the 32 bit version. This didn't help (same issue).

But then I tried something different. So my workspace was originally my Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 (as I had many AS3 projects in that workspace and wanted to just load that up in 4.7). Apparently this caused my issue (or at least it went away when I did the following).

I decided to use Flash Builder 4.7's default workspace (Users\\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7) instead of switching to 4.6. I then imported my existing projects that lived in my 4.6 directory. Compiled and it ran fine!

I guess there is an issue when upgrading from Flash Builder 4.6 to 4.7 and using the old workspaces from 4.6... Not sure why it caused that bizarre error but I'm glad to be able to move on.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me. I fixed this by:

Project -> Properties -> Library Path ->

clearing out the old libraries here from fb 4.6 and clicking 'add air sdk'.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It turned out to be because in

Project -> Properties -> Library path

**An earlier version of playerGlobal.swc was referenced rather than the default one provided as part of the Air SDK. Removing that and manually adding the playerGlobal SWC from the Air SDK resolved the problem**.

(Apparently Playerglobal.swc includes just the interface definitions, including native methods, for classes that are in the Player).

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me (may help someone else as well).

I am on FB 4.6 and I remember well that I updated my SDK to Apatche 13.0. After that libraries in my projects messed up. I removed project (also deleted files) and than imported copy of the same project again. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was in the build script. I upgraded to AIR SDK 22, but the build task contained:

```
<target-player>11.1</target-player>
```

Either removing this parameter or changing the value to 23.0 solved the problem.