# how to fullscreen with keyboard input enable on flex 3.6a sdk? theres no class on StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex3, flash-builder

i tried using fullscreen interactive using 4.6a sdk but i need to run my application on 3.6a sdk ..can somebody tell how can i solve this..i cannot change my flex application because   some class are not compatible on 4.6a. is there a plugin that i can import on my flex app?here's the sample code

```
try {
                switch (Application.application.stage.displayState) {
                    case StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN:
                    case StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE:
                        /* If already in full screen mode, switch to normal mode. */
                        Application.application.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;

                        break;
                    default:
                        /* If not in full screen mode, switch to full screen mode. */
                        trace("flash version"+Capabilities.version);
                        Application.application.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

                        break;
                }
            } catch (err:SecurityError) {
                // ignore
            }
```

1119: Access of possibly undefined property FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE through a reference with static type Class.

Answer (score 2):

You must use playerglobal.swc for Flash Player 11.3 or later to get access to newer APIs. Flex SDK 3.6 only has playerglobal.swc included for FP versions 9 and 10, You can download the most recent playerglobal.swc (11.7) from [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html). Then place it in the "Adobe Flash Builder\sdks\3.6.0\frameworks\libs\player\11\" dir, select appropriate player version in the project settings and that should do.

Comment: error when running the app VerifyError: Error #1079: Native methods are not allowed in loaded code.

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638283/verifyerror-error-1079-native-methods-are-not-allowed-in-loaded-code